# Remove Sprockets from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

How do you remove Sprockets from Rails?

I've..

- removed all the Sprockets Gems.
- removed all the `config.assets.*` from initializers, etc..

Still, Rails is looking for Sprockets

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:105:in block in <class:Railtie>': Expected to find a manifest file in `app/assets/config/manifest.js (Sprockets::Railtie::ManifestNeededError)
```

......

```
 Example:
13:58:38 web.1  |   //= link_tree ../images
13:58:38 web.1  |   //= link_directory ../javascripts .js
13:58:38 web.1  |   //= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

How do you actually remove Sprockets?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you've "removed all the Sprockets Gems"? Is it still in your `Gemfile` or `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: I've removed it from Gemfile. Bundled. But it still exisits in Gemfile.lock. `sprockets-rails`

Comment: You should be able to tell from the `Gemfile.lock` what depends on it. You may also need to do a `bundle update sprockets-rails`. You can also do this in one step with [`bundle remove sprockets-rails`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-remove.1.html).

Comment: Its nested under `rails (6.0.2.1)`. I've removed it with bundler. It removes it from Gemfile, but it remains in Gemfile.lock

Comment: did you remove `require "sprockets/railtie"` from `config/application.rb`?

Comment: I'm not seeing any refs to sprockets in my app at all.
`config.load_defaults 6.0` is the only config in application.rb

Comment: Was the app created as a Rails 6 application or migrated? In older Rails apps you might just have [`require "rails/all"`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb) while the generated application.rb in new versions will require each railtie explicitly.

Comment: Yup. Just caught that. `require 'rails/all'` is the culprit.

Comment: It was migrated from 5 app.

Comment: Replaced it with individual requires and it works. If you want to add the answer I'll accept it..

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to remove it from the Gemfile.lock as it's a runtime dependency of the the rails gem.  bundler complains

Answer (score 28):

To completely remove sprockets from a Rails project:

**Remove:**

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
```

from **Gemfile** then run `bundle install`.

**Replace:**

```
require 'rails/all'
```

**with:**

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

in **config/application.rb** file.

**Remove:**

```
# Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
config.assets.debug = true

# Suppress logger output for asset requests.
config.assets.quiet = true
```

from **config/environments/development.rb** file.

**Remove:**

```
# Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = false
```

from **config/environments/production.rb** file.

**Remove** **config/initializers/assets.rb** file.

You can also remove **app/assets** folder but it is not necessary because you may need it later if you changed your mind.

Comment: Hi, I'm Using Rails 5.2.4 and I did exactly as you said. However, sprockets-rails is still a dependency for rails in my Gemfile.lock and it is used at runtime. I want to remove it to save memory. How can I do that ?

Comment: You'd also want to remove `gem 'sprockets-rails'` in case you have it in your Gemfile

Comment: I add all this (rails 6.1.3) and still get: `Expected to find a manifest file in app/assets/config/manifest.js (Sprockets::Railtie::ManifestNeededError)`

Comment: @rigyt seems like the sprocket https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/1a0cf7a4572d0ee728d3dda2013d3305a77932f1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L71-L81 is still running. most likely you haven't remove  ```require "sprockets/railtie"``` in application.rb

Comment: Even if you do all of this, there is still a dependency on sprockets-rails from rails. I am using rails version 6.1.4.6 and it requires sprockets-rails. I tried removing every dependency of sprockets in Gemfile.lock, but then the application will not load.